# Android: How to take a live camera-shot and view it in Webview?

Tags: java, url, webview, dialog, box

[image: This is capture live camera image in dialog box .1]

when i open this in url in chrome its working fine when i open this url in webview this error is showing i just want to now how to resolve this issue even i give camera access permission and all permsion which is required..

is this error of dialog box if yes then share some code.

```
public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
  if (check_permission(2) && check_permission(3)) {
    if (ASWP_FUPLOAD) {
      if (asw_file_path != null) {
        asw_file_path.onReceiveValue(null);
      }
      asw_file_path = filePathCallback;
      Intent takePictureIntent = null;
      if (ASWP_CAMUPLOAD) {
        takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
          File photoFile = null;
          try {
            photoFile = create_image();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", asw_cam_message);
          } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
          }
          if (photoFile != null) {
            asw_cam_message = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
          } else {
            takePictureIntent = null;
          }
        }
      }
      Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CAMERA_BUTTON);
      if (!ASWP_ONLYCAM) {
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType(ASWV_F_TYPE);
        if (ASWP_MULFILE) {
          contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        }
      }
      Intent[] intentArray;
      if (takePictureIntent != null) {
        intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
      } else {
        intentArray = new Intent[0];
      }

      Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
      chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
      chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, getString(R.string.fl_chooser));
      chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
      startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, asw_file_req);
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    get_file();
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image]